# Need help to cover {get; set;} methods on a TestClass

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, getter, setter

i need some help on a TestClass as i said above, bellow i wil show you what the class looks like and the TestClass:

APEX CLASS:

```
public with sharing class DirectDebitController {

    public class AccountAmount {
        @AuraEnabled
        public Id accountId {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String accountName {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public string sortCode {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String accountNumber {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public Decimal amount {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<Invoice_Header__c> invoicesToBePaid {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public Integer numberOfAccounts {get; set;}

        public AccountAmount(Id accountId, String accountName, String sortCode, String accountNumber, Decimal amount, List<Invoice_Header__c> invoicesToBePaid, Integer numberOfAccounts) {

            this.accountId = accountId;            
            this.accountName = accountName;
            this.sortCode = sortCode;
            this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
            this.amount = amount;
            this.invoicesToBePaid = invoicesToBePaid;
            this.numberOfAccounts = numberOfAccounts;
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<AccountAmount> fillTable() {
        List<AccountAmount> accounts = new List<AccountAmount>();
        List < Account > accountsAndAmounts = [SELECT Name, Payment_Account_Number__c, Payment_Sort_Code__c, (SELECT Id, AmountOutstanding__c FROM Invoice_Headers__r WHERE AmountOutstanding__c > 0 AND ToPublish__c = true AND Query__c = false AND Overdue_Days__c > 0) FROM Account WHERE Enqix_Payment_Method__c = 'Direct Debit'
            AND Id IN(SELECT Account__c FROM Invoice_Header__c WHERE AmountOutstanding__c > 0 AND ToPublish__c = true AND Query__c = false AND Overdue_Days__c > 0) order by Name];
        Integer numberOfAccounts = Database.countQuery('SELECT COUNT() FROM Account WHERE Enqix_Payment_Method__c = \'Direct Debit\' AND Id IN(SELECT Account__c FROM Invoice_Header__c WHERE AmountOutstanding__c > 0 AND ToPublish__c = true AND Query__c = false AND Overdue_Days__c > 0)');
        for (Account a : accountsAndAmounts) {
            List<Invoice_Header__c> invoices = new List<Invoice_Header__c>();
            Decimal amount = 0;
            for (Invoice_Header__c i : a.Invoice_Headers__r) {
                amount += i.AmountOutstanding__c;
                invoices.add(i);
            }
            AccountAmount aa = new AccountAmount(a.Id, a.Name, a.Payment_Sort_Code__c, a.Payment_Account_Number__c, amount, invoices, numberOfAccounts);
            accounts.add(aa);
        }
        return accounts;

    }
}
```

TESTCLASS :

```
@isTest
private class DirectDebitControllerTest {

  @isTest
    static void TestfillTable(){        

        Account novaConta = new Account(
            Name = 'TESTE Account',
            Enqix_Payment_Method__c = 'Direct Debit',
            Payment_Account_Number__c = '123',
            Payment_Sort_Code__c = '321',
            Credit_Days__c = 200           
        );
        insert novaConta;
        system.debug('NOVA INVOICE'+ novaConta);

        Invoice_Header__c header = new Invoice_Header__c(
            Name = 'TESTE header',
            Account__c = novaConta.Id,
            Salesforce__c = false,
            CreatedDate__c = Date.newInstance(2016, 11, 11),
            Query__c = False,
            AmountOutstanding__c = 2000 
        );
        insert header;

        Account accountTest = [Select Id, Name, Enqix_Payment_Method__c, Payment_Account_Number__c, Payment_Sort_Code__c, Credit_Days__c from Account where Id =: novaConta.Id];
        Invoice_Header__c headerInserido = [Select Id, Query__c, ToPublish__c, Account__c, AmountOutstanding__c, Salesforce__c, Payment_Due_Date__c, Overdue_Days__c from Invoice_Header__c Where Id = :header.Id][0];
        //system.debug('Header novo '+ header + ' ToPublish está a true? = ' + header.ToPublish__c);
        system.debug('Header novo '+ headerInserido + ' ToPublish está a true? = ' + headerInserido.ToPublish__c + ' Overdue_Days valor? = ' + headerInserido.Overdue_Days__c);

        DirectDebitController.fillTable();
        //DirectDebitController.sendEmailWithAttachment(List<Account> accountTest);
    }
}
```

If you need some input from me just ask, but i really could use some help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Covering those lines is easy, and you may want to use an assert to do it. You can do it two ways.

Easy (and not best practice)

```
DirectDebitController.AccountAmount aa = new DirectDebitController.AccountAmount(<provide parameters>);
aa.accountId = <someValue>;
(do the same for all your properties)
```

Harder (but best practice since it helps you assert the behavior). Add this to the end of your test method.

```
List<DirectDebitController.AccountAmount> aaRecs = DirectDebitController.fillTable();
for (DirectDebitController.AccountAmount aa : aaRecs) {
  System.assertEquals(<valueToCompare>, aa.accountId);
  <do this for all your properties>
}
```

The second way not only covers and exercises your code, but it also verifies that your list is populated with the values you expect it to have.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian Kessel , first of all thank you for the response, the two options are returning an error saying the AccountAmount is a Invalid Type. error message:  'Invalid type: AccountAmount'

Comment: Fixed the code for you. Remember that you have to fully qualify inner classes.

Comment: that fixed the error TY, i will keep in mind to fully qualify the inner  classes, my bad.